# How to disable Microsoft Edge WebView2 and Node.js Server-side Javascript - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, child-process, visual-studio-2022

[image]

As you can see, under Vs2022 process, there are 33 child processes, with a lot of Edge WebView2. It has consumed a lot of memory of my computer. Similar to Nodejs Server-side JavaScript processes. My project is a web API project, and I think it's not necessary to have those processes. I only have 8G Ram, so I would like to VS launch as light as possible. How can I disable unnecessary services of VS2022 like that?

Comment: These processes seem to be related to LiveShare (node.js) and IntelliTrace (WebView2).  If you turn off those features, those processes should not get started.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I disabled the Live Share 2022 Extension and the processes went away.

From the main menu

- Extensions->Manage Extensions
- choose "Installed"
- select "Live Share 2022"
- click "Disable" (or uninstall)

Restart Visual Studio